# Kubernetes Cron Job for postgres db backup

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, database-backups, kubernetes-cronjob

Iam trying to create a cron job like this:

```js
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: postgres-backup
spec:
  # Backup the database every day at 2AM
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: postgres-backup
            image: postgres:10.4
            command: ["/bin/bash"]
            args: ["-c", 'PGPASSWORD="$PGPASS" pg_dump -U postgresadmin -h postgres example > /var/backups/backup-$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M").sql']
            env:
            - name: PGPASS
              value: admin123
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-pv-volume
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: postgres-pv-volume
            hostPath:
            # Ensure the file directory is created.
              path: /var/volumes/postgres-backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

When iam running the crone job the pods getting created with status created. But i was not able to see the backup files in my postgres pod. I think the backup file getting created in the same cronjob pod but how to access the completed pod.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, welcome to SO. The files will not be created in your postgres pod, they live in the `hostPath` on the Node upon which that Pod was scheduled. If you wish for that to be one Node all the time, you can use `nodeSelector:` or `nodeName:` in your PodSpec to tell kubernetes that desire

Comment: Also, there's no reason to re-declare the `PGPASSWORD` env-var inside your shell script; just change `- name: PGPASS` to `- name: PGPASSWORD` and then you and `psql` are on the same page; you'll also want `-ec` so that bash will exit with a non-zero exit code if that psql (or the redirect!) do not go as planned

Comment: Hello @Rajesh, did you find a solution?

Comment: No @Mikolaj , do you have any reference for postgresdb backup on kubernetes

Comment: @RajeshDavuluri, You can make a [snapshot of volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/#introduction). "Volume snapshots provide Kubernetes users with a standardized way to copy a volume's contents at a particular point in time without creating an entirely new volume. This functionality enables, for example, database administrators to backup databases before performing edit or delete modifications."

Answer (score 0):

Like mdaniel mentioned in the comment, you are using the volume type hostPath, which is a path on the node, so I guess in order for you to find the file being created, you need to login to that node and look under that path on the node.

And personally I don't think you should try to store it in the pod at all, since `Job` is run to complete, which means you are not able to retrieve anything in it when the job is completed.